# WARNING en POM.XML: aparece The Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load

Tags: java, warnings

Comunidad
¿ Alguien se le ha presentado este Warning al momento de ejecutar Tomcat v9.0? Solo he configurado el Pom; cambié la versión de java ( de 1.6 a 1.8, tanto en "properties" como en "source" y "target"( en "configuration"), y si se ejecuta en el localhost con "Hello World", pero me llama la atención que aparezca ese Warning. He visto un video y supuestamente o debieran haber warnings en la configuracion, sin haber creado proyecto adicional.

```
WARNING: The Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. The error reported was [C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2407)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:747)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:41)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(AprLifecycleListener.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
```

También me aparece este otro warning

```
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [132] milliseconds.
```

Agradezco sus respuestas, porque soy bastante nuevo en esto, y me es dificil dar facilmente con los errores o warnings ( tengo eclipse Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0), y jdk 15.0.2.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volví a reinstalar el mismo Apache Tomcat, pero esta vez, la carpeta Apache Software Foundation, quedo en instalada en "Archivos de programa" y no en "Archivos de programa(x86)" como la tenía cuando se me presentaba el warning. Creo haberlo visto en alguna publicación que decía que había que descargarlo en esa carpeta para 32 bit, pero no era así. Una vez instalado en la carpeta correcta, desapareció el warning.¡ Funcionó!

Answer (score 0):

Estás cargando una librería que no es. Te lo está diciendo. DLL compilado para 32bit en un OS de 64 bit.

La [documentación](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi) dice

> Each archive contains tcnative-1.dll for 32-bit and 64-bit (x64) CPU architectures. You have to use the DLL that matches CPU architecture of JVM that you use to run Tomcat.

Es decir (en una traducción libre) que debes poner la dll que corresponda con tu OS y elegiste la que no es.

VIendo la descarga del tcnative

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay una carpeta x64 con la dll correcta, y la de afuera presumo que es de 32bit.

Edito: De acuerdo a lo que comentas, recomendaría volver a empezr y asegurarte de descargar una versión 64bit de Tomcat. Asegúrate de usar el enlace a *64bit Windows zip*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba arrancar y usar este Tomcat sin cambiarle librerías y, si vuelves a tener el mismo lío que reportas en tu pregunta, descarga el TCnative y reemplaza la DLL.

Comment: Gracias alfabravo por tu respuesta; ingresé a la carpeta "bin" de  Tomcat 9.0 (Apache Software Foundation), y solo tengo un archivo tcnative-1.dll

Comment: @Juanpita40 Lo que te mostré es la descarga del instalador de TCnative. El instalador descargado tiene los dos DLL. Al descargarlo, puedes elegir cuál usar, reemplaza el que tiene tu tomcat por el que viene allí. La duda es de dónde sacaste ese Tomcat para que traiga cosas 32bit

Comment: @Juanpita40 actualicé la respuesta..

Comment: Volví a reinstalar el mismo Apache Tomcat, pero esta vez, la carpeta Apache Software Foundation, quedo en instalada en "Archivos de programa" y no en "Archivos de programa(x86)" como la tenía cuando se me presentaba el warning. Creo haberlo visto en alguna publicación que decía que había que descargarlo en esa carpeta para 32 bit, pero no era así. Una vez instalado en la carpeta correcta, desapareció el warning.

Comment: Donde se ponga no tiene nada que ver. Tampoco nos estás diciendo cómo instalaste tomcat (con el msi o con el zip). Lo importante es que lo resolviste y ojalá lo compartas con los demás